# SetThreadLocale on a process scope

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, locale

I know that if I want to change locale for my thread using LCID I can call [SetThreadLocale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but how do I set it on a process scope using LCID?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that with the WinApi. Locales are set per user and you cannot set the locale of a process, you are only allowed to set it per thread.

Comment: Thanks. Just curious what does `setlocale` do? I came across a lot of references to it.

Comment: It effects how all the C library functions behave. For example, `SetThreadLocale` has no effect on `printf`, only winapi functions. It probably would be better to call both though in your program.

Comment: Thanks again. So what if I want to change the language that is used in my program, how do I do that? (Language for resources that are loaded.)

Comment: @c00000fd: See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc194810.aspx) and [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/89866/en-us). You will want to use the `LANGUAGE` identifier in your resource file and call `FindResourceEx` to find the resource based on language.

Comment: Thanks. I followed the articles but still couldn't set my app to work with the resource language I want. I made a small test solution to illustrate. Can you check: https://www.dropbox.com/s/taquznehe0wd7i2/TestMultiLangRes.zip I use the following lines in constructor for CTestMultiLangResApp: `SetThreadLocale(MAKELCID(MAKELANGID(LANG_GERMAN, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), SORT_DEFAULT)); setlocale(LC_ALL, "german");` but it doesn't seem to have any effect. My Windows user language UI is US English.

Comment: @c00000fd: Although I'd like to help, I'd rather not download a zip file. Why don't you make another question and post the code? Or post the code somewhere else and I will take a look (also, I won't be able to respond very soon after this due to other affairs).

Comment: It's an MFC/C++ stock project from Visual Studio. The code I added is in my post above, but there's also a German resource added to the project. I don't know how else I can post it?

Answer (score 1):

LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT is the default locale for the user or process.
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> When a thread is created, it uses the user locale. This user locale can be modified for future processes and thread creation using the regional and language options portion of the Control Panel.

Comment: Thanks, I know that. My goal is to set the locale/culture that is used in my program to load resources.

Comment: Please see if this link helps (Give importance to last paragraphs): 

    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc194810.aspx

Comment: Thanks, too. I read through the article and still couldn't make it work. See my post below for Jesse Good. Can you check my test solution why it doesn't seem to work?